# mysqli_fetch_array() returning NULL instead of value of COUNT()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the code `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM blog.posts WHERE hidden='0'` to find out how many pages to generate for pagination on a website. This query returns the following table;

```
|COUNT(id)|
|9        |
```

But I've ran into an issue. My PHP script to handle this information echos ''. Instead of the expected value '9'.

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$pages=mysqli_fetch_array($conn);
echo $pages[0];
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: COUNT won't give you the table size. It will return the total records in your table.

Comment: @VuralAcar Edited, that is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter for the `mysqli_fetch_array()` or any of the `mysqli_fetch_*` api calls should be a `mysqli_result` and not a connection object

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$pages = mysqli_fetch_array($result);    //<--- change
echo $pages[0];
```

Comment: Oh, spot on squire!

Answer (score 0):

try: 
`SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM blog.posts WHERE hidden='0'`

and then:

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$pages=mysqli_fetch_array($conn);
echo $pages['count'];
```

Comment: No such luck, it still returns 'p'.

Comment: did you see you don't have the '$' sign in your line of code: echo pages[0]; ?

Comment: I didn't catch that, fixed, but now it returns null.